# The extension of a file with JS HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to test the extension of a given file

> JS

```
function get_extension(file_name) {
    return file_name.split('.').pop();
}

function check_file_type(file) { 

    switch(get_extension(file)) {
        case 'jpg': case 'gif': case 'png':
            var element = document.getElementById('p');
            element.innerHTML = "Je suis une image";
            break;

        case 'mp4' :
            var element = document.getElementById('p');
            element.innerHTML = "Je suis une video";

    }
}
```

> HTML

```
   <button onclick="check_file_type(<%=(chemin_photo1)%>)">Click me!</button> 
   <p id="p"></p>
```

But it will show nothing, thank you in advance

Comment: Your code is working just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/6or7fpxg/. Please create a code snippet that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Just a side note, even if you do get the extension as say "JPG" there's no guarantee that the file is an image, or in the JPEG format.

Comment: I recommend changing `switch(get_extension(file).toLowerCase()) {` for extensions that are not fully lowercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose `chemin_photo1` is a string, not the name of a global variable, so you'll need to wrap it in quotes

```
<button onclick="check_file_type('<%=(chemin_photo1)%>')">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should consider a few things here.
First what comes from the server. As @Frederico suggested, it must be quoted as it is supposed to be a file name (string)

```
<button onclick="check_file_type('<%=(chemin_photo1)%>')">Click me!</button>
```

Next, you must always check what the value of the argument passed is. It should be at the beginning of the function or as a **default** in your **case** block because even if you have quoted the server output it could still be an empty string ('') and in your case, it'd seem not working.

```
function check_file_type(file) { 

    var element = document.getElementById('p');

    switch(get_extension(file)) {
        case 'jpg': case 'gif': case 'png':
            element.innerHTML = "Je suis une image";
            break;

        case 'mp4' :
            element.innerHTML = "Je suis une video";
            break;

        default:
            element.innerHTML = "oh-la-la!";
            break;
    }
}
```